# How to resolve system call out exception

Tags: webservices, callout

I am new to webservice task . I am getting an exception like

> System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: WebService
>   returned a SOAP Fault: Internal Error faultcode=env:Client faultactor=

I know what is callout but dont have any idea about the remaining things specified here .
Please tell me how to resolve and what exactly the error is about ?

Comment: it will be great if you can post your code as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this done in two different ways

1. on callout failure, use apex to recreate your outbound xml, send it using httpRequest and parse the response xml to get your error message
2. add an 'error' string field to the response class. You then do your webservice call to an intermediate layer which hides these exceptions and always returns to salesforce a 'valid' response.

both of which are just workarounds to salesforce limitations